# How can I remove the subquery from the select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, common-table-expression, denodo

I need help in removing the subquery out of the original SELECT statement. Is this even possible? I'm needing this to ultimately move queries like this to Denodo/VQL, which doesn't allow subqueries in SELECT statements (but does allow CTE/WITH and subqueries in FROM/WHERE).

```
select case when material in (
    select material
    from schema.material_table
    where old_material like '%55AD%'
  ) then 'Found'
  else 'Not Found'
end
from schema.material_table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of options. The most direct translation seems to be:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN m2.MATERIAL IS NOT NULL THEN 'Found'
         ELSE 'Not Found'
       END AS IZZIT_THERE
  FROM SCHEMA.MATERIAL_TABLE m2
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.MATERIAL_TABLE m1
    ON m1.MATERIAL = m2.MATERIAL
  WHERE m1.OLD_MATERIAL LIKE '%55AD%'
```

but the use of a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` may be unfamiliar. To switch to the more familiar `LEFT OUTER JOIN` we need to reverse the position of the tables in the query and alter how the conditions are presented:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN m1.MATERIAL IS NOT NULL THEN 'Found'
         ELSE 'Not Found'
       END AS IZZIT_THERE
  FROM SCHEMA.MATERIAL_TABLE m1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.MATERIAL_TABLE m2
    ON m2.MATERIAL = m1.MATERIAL
  WHERE m1.OLD_MATERIAL LIKE '%55AD%'
```

I kept the aliases the same so you can see how they moved around in the query. In both queries `m1` is the primary table, that is, it's the one that *must* provide data, while `m2` is the secondary or "optional" table - it may or may not have data which matches the primary.

Personally, I prefer joins over subqueries as I find them easier to understand, but YMMV.